# C# passing an Action<> into another Action<>

Tags: c#, loops, parameters, delegates, action

I am new to delegates and I am trying to pass an Action<> as a parameter of another Action<>.
For example, (with code re-usability in mind) I was attempting to make a loop action and pass other actions into it to reduce the number of loops in my code:

```
Action<int, Action<Control, Control>> loop = (int stop, Action<Control, Control> action) =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < stop; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < stop; j++)
        {
            <action> pass Add;
        }
    }
};

Action<Control, Control> Add = (Control Parent, Control Child) => Parent.Controls.Add(Child);
```

The main objective is to be able to re-use the double for loop in such a way where I can mix and match the action inside of it with other actions.

Comment: you should probably explain what you are trying to do here

Comment: *with code re-usability in mind* don't obfuscate your code, it may go hard to follow code. Really you're not going to get any benefit just by reusing this for loop.

Comment: The only think you can do inside your loops is to invoke `action` delegate, which would require you to have two `Control` instances. Doesn't seem that you have them.

Comment: I guess the main goal is to be able to re-use the double loop action since I need it a lot for the program I'm working on and it seems like a waste of lines to repeat it over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Action<int, Action<Control, Control>> loop = (int stop, Action<Control, Control> action) =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < stop; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < stop; j++)
        {
            //// invoke action with real arguments
            // action(controlParent, controlChild);
        }
    }
};

Action<Control, Control> Add = (Control Parent, Control Child) => Parent.Controls.Add(Child);

loop(1, Add);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your action usage is not bad if you want the loop in main action using another action.